# How can I make select in select on laravel eloquent?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3, eloquent

I use laravel 5.3

My sql query is like this :

```
SELECT * 
FROM (
    SELECT *
    FROM products 
    WHERE `status` = 1 AND `stock` > 0 AND category_id = 5
    ORDER BY updated_at DESC
    LIMIT 4
) AS product
GROUP BY store_id
```

I want to change it to be laravel eloquent

But I'm still confused

How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In cases when your query is to complex you can laravel `RAW` query syntax like:

```
$data = DB::select(DB::raw('your query here'));
```

It will fire your raw query on the specified table and returns the result set, if any.

[Reference](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/queries#raw-expressions)

Answer (score 0):

If you have Product model, you can run

```
$products = Product::where('status', 1)
->where('stock', '>', 0)
->where('category_id', '=', 5)
->groupBy('store_id')
->orderBy('updated_at', 'desc')
->take(4)
->get();
```

I think this should give you the same result since you pull everything from your derived table.

Comment: I think the point in his question is how to get a select inside a select, not the intricacies of the inner select.

Comment: @EddyTheDove, It works. But, the `order by` not executed